# Get menu link item of a currently provided route in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I would like to get the menu link item of a provided route `/people/scientists`:

```
$menu_link = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('menu_link_content')
                ->loadByProperties(['link.uri' => 'entity:/people/scientists']);
```

But for some reason it returns an empty array. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

in my empty sample data, menu_link_content_data table have `link_uri` column
so i think you could try this:

```
loadByProperties(['link_uri' => 'entity:/people/scientists'])
```

[image: sample]